# Using a punching bag without stand

Tags: boxing, punching

I don't have place to hanging a punching bag, so I would like to know if it's good to place a punching bag leaning on the wall and punch it?

Comment: House or apartment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't ideal.  I don't think you're going to get much out of it, because part of punching bag training is reacting to the return swing.  Additionally, some of your force will be transferred through the bag into the wall, which could possibly damage the wall if it's dry-wall.  Also, the bag will probably not be the right height to punch without having to compromise your body structure.

You also won't be able to deliver round kicks with your shin, because your foot needs to clear the rear of the bag.  I know you're only asking about punching, but just in case you want to kick, I thought I'd mention it.

There exist free-standing heavy bag stands, if it's the case that you just don't want to hang the bag from the ceiling.  These are usually held in place with weights of the kind that you bench-press on the rear of the stand.

If you just want to punch something, and you aren't concerned with having a swinging target, you have two options:

- Buy a kick shield.  Have a friend hold it, or find some way to strap it to a tree.
- Punch a tree.  Just don't do it hard, and find a tree with smooth bark.  You won't be able to work your techniques as intensely as with a punching bag, but it *is* an option.  You may consider wearing hand-wraps for this purpose.

Comment: thank you, may be i have to find a cheap stand to hang it :)

Comment: Or, hey, another handy use for trees: they have branches.  You can hang the punching bag from a sturdy branch with some rope.  Even apartment dwellers can sometimes get away with this, provided there is wooded area around their apartment complex.  Just remember to take it down when you're done :)

Comment: Strapping a kick shield to a tree is a *really* bad idea. Very easy to miss and cause damage, the tree doesn't give way on hard impacts, and you can't really wrap your foot. Lots of easy ways to get injured.

Comment: @JohnP, this is in reference to punching, not kicking.

Comment: Ah. Not quite as bad an idea, I still don't like having a complete unforgiving backdrop, but not as bad as kicking. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand on The Wudang Kid's answer in that I found a stand on Amazon for about $100. Alternatively you could also pick up a BOB but those are significantly more expensive, around $270. Should you go the tree route as suggested above I would definitely suggest at minimum hand wraps and nomex gloves and definitely go lighter on the punches. Hope this helps, good luck in your training.

Knowledge source: Muay Thai figher, new jiujitsu practitioner, trained in Taekwondo, Boxing, and Muay Thai for over a decade.